# How can I use VS Code's default keybindings in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I want to use the default VS Code key bindings in Visual Studio, such as <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> for example.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050877/make-visual-studio-use-vs-code-shortcut-keys-key-bindings).

[image]

Comment: IIRC, this option wasn't available when I posted this question. So I have accepted your answer as it provides a better way than the previous one!

Comment: not being able to multi select with `CTRL + ALT UP/DOWN`  was a pain in the arse, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I implemented this suggested solution and nothing changed in my Visual Studio shortcuts. Example: ```Shift + Alt + DownArrow``` still copies the carat down a line, as opposed to copying the current line, which is the expected VSCode based behavior.

Comment: same here, the original shortcuts done seem to be affected at all

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would want to switch from VS Code to Visual Studio... I am sure there is reason though just being a little sarcastic.  This is a link that talks about key bindings in Visual Studio, not sure what version you're using.[Key Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio)

However, I know you can import these settings into Visual Studio but follows a specific file extension.  Probably not helpful, I wonder if there is some NuGet package that could incorporate those settings.

Regardless, for the most they are both Microsoft Products.  Last I checked the shortcuts for the most part are fairly similar. If you're looking for something specific or want something specific I'd just modify it in the key bindings link above.

Comment: I've been using VSCode for sometime and they suggested VS for C# at my new internship. I have never used C# so I don't know how supportive VSCode is for it. Do you have any insight into it? If I wouldn't lose anything by using VSCode I'd love to.

Comment: I am a very big advocate for VS Code.  And yes you can use C# in VS Code, there is an extension for it.  Visual Studio is your standard IDE for .NET based code, C#, F#, VisualBasic, etc.  But you don't have to use C# in Visual Studio.  There is also .NET Core which is an open sourced version of Visual Studio/.NET development.  If you're a beginner and just learning and nothing wrong with Visual Studio is a little more friendlier than the others.  You should do what you feel comfortable with, where you'll learn the best. Good luck to you

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp That's how you use VS Code for C#

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it

Comment: Are you really comparing VS Code to Visual Studio ? Assuming you really have no idea, in Visual Studio you don't find yourself searching the internet for the most basic things like "How do I start?!" and "How do I debug?!" and you don't waste your time boilerplating again and again... Seems like going back to the 80s. The only reason I am forced to work with VS Code is because some extensions are only there now, the organization is horrific, even though the Solution Explorer extension make it a bit better.