# Make Visual Studio use VS code shortcut keys / key bindings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, settings, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I've been using VSCode a lot lately and have gotten used to the keys-shortcuts/key-bindings (Ctrl+D, Ctrl+P, Alt+leftArrow, etc). However I've recently had some work where I needed to use regular Visual Studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019) and it's painful remembering two different shortcut keys.

Is there a way to import VSCode key-shortcuts to into regular Visual Studio?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786288/how-to-import-vscode-keybindings-into-visual-studio) and there wasn't much help besides manually changing them one at a time.

UPDATE: now the above post answers the question now that I posed Francois du Plessis's answer there.

Comment: Found this `.vssetting` file with some of VS Code shortcuts: https://gist.github.com/jaywick/588ea04e11f74c726a9eed3ccc684bf6  . To be used in Visual Studio it needs to be imported via `Tools`->`Import and Export Settings` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#to-import-only-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: @Renat I need to try this out. Can you move this to one of the answers so you can get credit?

Comment: Thanks, but Francois du Plessis' answer is actually a correct one for Visual Studio 2019. So I will leave mine as a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import VSCode keybindings into Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786288/how-to-import-vscode-keybindings-into-visual-studio)

Comment: @Mikael now it does answer the question( Now that I posted the answer there ).

Comment: @RayLoveless my bad, I mistakenly flagged the question as duplicate and promptly removed the flag a few seconds later, this comment seems to be auto generated.

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite? I want my VS shortcuts in VSCode

Comment: For the opposite side, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vs-keybindings

Answer (score 199, accepted):

If you go to **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard**. There should be an option to select Visual Studio Code as a Keyboard mapping scheme
[image: Screenshot of the configuration]

Comment: I'm not getting all of the functionality of the vscode key bindings. Could something be interfering? Specifically ctrl+d still copy/paste my current selected text.

Comment: @JayJordan I believe something might be interfering, testing ctrl+d on both VS Code and VS 2019 (Version 16.7.2) selects the next occurrence of the current selection for me

Comment: I have a feeling that Jetbrains Resharper is probably the culprit.

Comment: On 8.10.8 for Mac I found this on Preferences > Key Bindings > Scheme (the dropdown)

Comment: Amazing! Just wondering... wth my VS 2022 has its default set to VC++ 6? 

Comment: what about the other way around? Visual Studio 2022 C# keybindings to VS Code?

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own settings file based on an existing Visual Studio file.
Simply add your settings to it from VSCode keybinding setting file.

VSCode's keybinding settings is stored in `keybindings.json` json-formated file.
open file in menu
`File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts`
or on Windows file path like that
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Code\..\keybindings.json`

Visual Studio's keybinding settings is stored in `CurrentSettings.vssettings` xml-formated file.
on VS menu:
`Tools->Import and Export Settings`
then select 'Import select environment setting' radiobutton and click 'Next'
you'll see browser for import your file.
on Windows file path like that
`C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Settings\`

You can read more about it at this:
[Make Visual Studio use VS code shortcut keys/key bindings](https://newbedev.com/make-visual-studio-use-vs-code-shortcut-keys-key-bindings)

Comment: visual studio only imports `.vssettings` file. how can I import `keyboardbindings.json`

Comment: @Abraham you can try to create your own `.vssettings` based on `keyboardbindings.json` and than try to import it to Visual Studio.

Comment: This is a 1:1 copy from https://newbedev.com/make-visual-studio-use-vs-code-shortcut-keys-key-bindings . Please refer to the sources when you quote like this.

Comment: @Markus source link has been added

Comment: @timnavigate How do you create your own `.vsettings` based on the json file

Comment: @BobtheBuilder unfortunately, only in manual mode

Comment: @timnavigate what is manual mode

Comment: @BobtheBuilder  I meant that to create a `.vssettings` file, you can manually write xml-code of setting, manually transfer xml-syntax to json-syntax of `keybindings.json` file.

Comment: @Markus i think that Newbedev is one of those sites that just scrape StackOverflow and make it look like they wrote it. https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/pozzgr/what_is_newbedev_and_how_are_they_getting_away/