# How to use VScode Keybindings in Visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, shortcut, key-bindings

I need to use Visual studio 2019 for my school, I love the VSCode shortcuts (for Example ALT+SHIFT+Down - duplicates a line) but I  can't seem to figure out how to use them in Visual studio 2019.

I already tried the answer provided: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786288/how-to-import-vscode-keybindings-into-visual-studio) , didn't work.

I tried to copy the JSON keybindings file from VSCode but Visual Studio 2019 keybindings doesn't seem to work that way.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: a keybinding is linked to a command of the editor/IDE, if that command is not available than you can't do that, otherwise change the keybinding VS19 has defined to what you want

Comment: Just use VSC for your editing and do the other stuff in VS19