# How to use Visual Studio Code keybindings in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I know that you can select the option ‘Visual Studio Code’ in keybinds on Visual Studio, but the problem is that not all keybindings work in the same way. For example, one of the features I like most in VS Code is ‘Shift + Alt + ⇵’ to copy the selected line/block up or down, but this doesn’t work in Visual Studio. I have already tried this tutorial: [How can I use VS Code's default keybindings in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786288/how-to-import-vscode-keybindings-into-visual-studio), but it didn’t work.

If Visual Studio doesn’t have the option to import all key bindings, does anyone know the name of the shortcut to do the same as ‘Shift + Alt + ⇵’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the record button on the right side of the keyboard shortcut to check which of your VS shortcut keys are repeated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txmcs.png)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation, but, where is this option?

Comment: There is an image shown in my answer, you can click to view it，it is 【enter imgae description here】

Comment: Sorry, I just understood your question. The entrance to this options is: File-Preferences-Keyboard Shortcuts. 

Hope this answer can help you

Comment: Thanks very much, i found it. But i still think Visual Studio doesn't have the option to copy/paste like VSCode does with ‘Shift + Alt + ⇵’

Comment: I downloaded this software, but I also haven’t found any editor that. I’m sorry that I can’t help you.

However, you can retrieve the current range of this shortcut key in your system,like that: https://ibb.co/1RZnKH2

Comment: Thanks very much, you helped me a lot. The link is broken but it's fine.